# How to update json file with values from the other json file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I have two json files: `config.json` and `update.json`. How to update the existing `config.json` file according to the values in `update.json`? The `key:value` in `update.json` will not include parent key information and assume all keys are unique. Is there a way to implement this in python?

`config.json`:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`update.json`:

```
{"ID": "ABC",
 "GlossSeeAlso": ["ABC", "DEF"]
}
```

The output of python should be something like this:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "ABC",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["ABC", "DEF"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to implement this using a recursive function:

```
def update(base, new):
    if isinstance(base, dict):
        for k, v in new.items():
            if k in base:
                base[k] = v
        return {k: update(v, new) for k, v in base.items()}
    else:
        return base
```

Just call this with your initial JSON object and the update mapping, and you'll get the output you provide in your question.

Comment: can you show how to do this for android in kotlin or java?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to load `json` files, you just have to modify a dictionary recursively:

```
def update_dict(d, key, new_value):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == key:
            d[k] = new_value
            return True
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            if update_dict(v, key, new_value):
                return True
    return False
```

This will modify the original dict, if you don't want that, use @scnerd solution.

You can then use it like this, where config is the dictionary to modify and update the dictionary with the values to change:

```
for k, v in update.items():
    update_dict(config, k, v)
```